# add content to an A4 size page in two equal parts using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Actually I'm generating an invoice format using iTextSharp in C# , and I need to divide A4 size page into two equal parts so in one page I need to print two invoice bills.

sample code

```
 foreach (DataColumn column in dt1.Columns)
        {
            PdfPCell columnname = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.ToString().ToUpper(), boldTableFont));
            columnname.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            itemTable.AddCell(columnname);
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
        {
            PdfPCell numberCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row["productid"].ToString(), bodyFont));
            numberCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            numberCell.PaddingLeft = 10f;
            numberCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER | iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER;
            itemTable.AddCell(numberCell);
```

}

Comment: Why are you using an old version of iText? In iText 7, you create a `ColumnDocumentRenderer` to achieve this. See [Chapter 3](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers) of the iText 7 jumpstart tutorial for .NET to find out how it works. The trick is to define the coordinates in such a way that the columns aren't next to each other as in the example, but each take half a page instead. Why are you using an old iText version?

Comment: indeed, your requirement is much easier to implement using iText 7. It is possible, though, with iText 5.5.x, too, simply look for `ColumnText` examples.